# Insert multiple documents in index at once, using VScode Azure Cognitive Services extension. (Azure Search Service)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cognitive-search

I want to insert multiple *Documents* at once into a *Index* in *Azure Search Service*. I am using VScode extension *Azure Cognitive Services* to insert as mentioned in their document.

Link to offical doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-vs-code

The official doc mentions the method to insert a single JSON i.e.**Right Click Document->Create new document**.

I tried to insert multiple JSON documents separated by comma (snipped attached below) using the above mentioned method, I get the error as expected:

```
Unexpected token, in JSON at position 915
```

My try to insert multiple documents in a single **Create new document**:

```
{
"HotelId": "4",
"HotelName": "Sublime Cliff Hotel",
"Description": "Sublime Cliff Hotel is located in the heart of the historic center of Sublime in an extremely vibrant and lively area within short walking distance to the sites and landmarks of the city and is surrounded by the extraordinary beauty of churches, buildings, shops and monuments. Sublime Cliff is part of a lovingly restored 1800 palace.",
"Description_fr": null,
"Category": "Boutique",
"Tags": [
    "concierge",
    "view",
    "24-hour front desk service"
],
"ParkingIncluded": true,
"LastRenovationDate": "1960-02-06T00:00:00Z",
"Rating": 4.6,
"Address": {
    "StreetAddress": "7400 San Pedro Ave",
    "City": "San Antonio",
    "StateProvince": "TX",
    "PostalCode": "78216",
    "Country": "USA"
}
},
{
"HotelId": "5",
"HotelName": "Sublime Cliff Hotel",
"Description": "Sublime Cliff Hotel is located in the heart of the historic center of Sublime in an extremely vibrant and lively area within short walking distance to the sites and landmarks of the city and is surrounded by the extraordinary beauty of churches, buildings, shops and monuments. Sublime Cliff is part of a lovingly restored 1800 palace.",
"Description_fr": null,
"Category": "Boutique",
"Tags": [
    "concierge",
    "view",
    "24-hour front desk service"
],
"ParkingIncluded": true,
"LastRenovationDate": "1960-02-06T00:00:00Z",
"Rating": 4.6,
"Address": {
    "StreetAddress": "7400 San Pedro Ave",
    "City": "San Antonio",
    "StateProvince": "TX",
    "PostalCode": "78216",
    "Country": "USA"
}
}
```

Does anyone know any method to insert multiple documents at once in a index using VScode?

Comment: Hi!  I've let the person who wrote VS Code extension for Cognitive Search know that you want this, and he is adding it as a feature request to the backlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing using *Postman* by creating a POST request with the JSON passed in the body. This works for both single as well as multiple documents entry into the *Index*.

Link for official doc-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-rest